# With ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro to set my printer settings. I prompt the user as to whether or not they want to print the current report. Based on which report they ran, I send the Header variable to this printer setup code.

If I "run" this, the Report Header does not change from one report to the next.
If I step through this code (f8) to a point 2 -3 lines past .CenterHeader = gblReportHeader and then press f5, the Report Header changes as I expect it to.

When I comment out the Application.PrintCommunication = line(s), the printpreview statement will flash the old report header and then display the proper report and header.

Any ideas why?

```
Sub PrintSettings(PrintZone)

' PrintSettings Macro               
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = PrintZone

Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = gblReportHeader
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
'        .PrintHeadings = False
'        .PrintGridlines = False
'        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
'        .CenterHorizontally = False
'        .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
'        .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
'        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
'        .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
'        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
'        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True

'    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
ActiveSheet.PrintPreview

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try adding the `DoEvents` function before the PrintPreview statement?

Comment: Yes, I tried it right after .CenterHeader = , right before End With, right after End With, and right before ActiveSheet.PrintPreview. 

No change.

Comment: I added a for next loop with doevents in it. All that does is slow the program down. From what I read on doevents, it's not a good coding technique to use.

Comment: It's not ideal, but it can help diagnose the problem. Can you clarify what you mean by "correct report" vs "proper report"? These 2 sound like the same thing to me.

Comment: Ignore (correct report). I think maybe I started my sentence then, changed it. I would change my comment but don't seem to be able to edit my original post.

Maybe you could expand on how you feel DoEvents can diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem!

I commented out every line within the With ActiveSheet.PageSetup statement that I felt I did not need. This resolved my issue. I then started removing the commented lines back until I narrowed the issue to 5 lines.

```
.LeftHeader = ""
.RightHeader = ""
.LeftFooter = ""
.CenterFooter = ""
.RightFooter = ""
```

I continued commenting these out one at a time and find that the .RightHeader = "" which is right after my .CenterHeader = gblReportHeader statement is the offending line of code.

I don't fully understand why but, being that these lines are not required, I have no qualms eliminating them so that my code works as expected.

Thank you to those who offered suggestions.